# get a table from 3 nested tables

Tags: java, mysql

I have 3 different tables:actor,film_actor and film.

```
table actor(first_name, last_name, actor_id);

table film_actor(actor_id, film_id);

table film(film_id, title);
```

I need to search all the titles by first name and last name of an actor.

```
    System.out.println("enter first name:");
                    String fName=s2.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("enter last name:");
                    String lName=s2.nextLine();
                    ResultSet myRes3_2 = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT title from film where film_id in"
                            + "(SELECT film_id from film_actor where actor_id in"
                            + "(SELECT actor_id FROM actor WHERE first_name="+fName+" and last_name="+lName+"))"); 

                    ResultSetMetaData meta3_2 = myRes3_2.getMetaData();

                    int numCol3_2 = meta3_2.getColumnCount();

                    while (myRes3_2.next()){

                        for(int i = 1 ; i <= numCol3_2; i++){

                            System.out.print(myRes3_2.getString(i) + " ,"); //Print one element of a row

                        }

                        System.out.println();
                    }
```

Comment: and what is your problem?

Comment: its just not working i get an error messege that the syntax is wrong

Comment: can you post your error please?